# Center a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to center a UITextField and this is my code :

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var sampleTextField = UITextField()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))

    view.addSubview(mainView)

    sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: mainView.center, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 20)))

    sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
    sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center

    mainView.addSubview(sampleTextField)
    }

}
```

But the UITextField doesn't appear because I think it is outside of the screen, so how could I center it in the screen?

Comment: I've never worked with SpriteKit, however are you using autolayout in your code?

Comment: No I am not using autolayout

Comment: Maybe you can check the didMove() function, put a debug pointer at the beginning of the function and inspect the size of the SKView, maybe at the time that function is called, the SKView has not been properly laid out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using center method:-

```
sampleTextField.center = CGPoint(x: value1, y: value2)
```

Comment: For some reason though when I set the center to x: 300, y: 550 the TextField appears in the bottom right corner when the size of the screen is really 750 in height and 1334 in height. Why does this happen?

Comment: Can't you pass the view.center??If you only want to center the textfield inside your view??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of..

```
sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: mainView.center, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 20)))
```

do this..

```
sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: mainView.center.x - 100, y: mainView.center.y - 10), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 20)))
```

The orgin of a `CGRect` is always on the top left corner. You need to subtract half of the width and height of the center point.